# Como não deixar o usuário clica mais de uma vez em botão usando javascript

Tags: javascript, html

Como não deixar o usuário clica mais de uma vez em botão usando javascript

```
<input type="submit" class="inviar" name="teste" id="testeid" value="Enviar">
```

Comment: Bem vindo ao site. Mas você deveria juntar tudo aqui nesse post da pergunta, o stack não é um forum, voce deve sempre adicionar informações no primeiro post(o da pergunta). Sugiro edita-la clicando em EDITAR  e apagar as respostas abaixo. Visite **[tour]** para conhecer melhor o site tambem :)

Comment: Outra coisa, sempre poste o código em forma textual, imagem só atrapalha testar.

Comment: Depende. Isso está dentro de um formulário? Se for um formulário comum, sem ajax, cada clique vai recarregar a página e se já foi clicado ou não precisaria ser resolvido do lado do servidor. Veja se alguma das respostas abaixo resolve sua dúvida, senão explique melhor o problema.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Em jquery voce pode fazer assim:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
     $("#send").one('click', function (e) {  
           $(this).prop('disabled', true);
     });
});
```

Answer (score 4):

Basta adicionar o [`disabled`](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_option_disabled.asp) para desabilitar o botão, sendo assim "dê um jeito" de adicionar o atributo ao ser clicado.

Uma das opções é simplesmente adicionar no `onClick`:

```html
<button onClick="this.disabled=true;">Teste</button>
```

Também pode fazer por Javascript, não existe necessidade de usar JQuery:

```js
document.getElementsByTagName("button")[0].addEventListener('click', function(){
     this.disabled = true;
});
```

```html
<button>Teste</button>
```

*Lembrando que o usuário pode remover esse comportamento, assim como replicar as requisições de outras formas.*

Answer (score 0):

O que pode fazer é ao clicar no botão, alterar a propriedade 'disabled' do botão para 'true':

Exemplo:

document.getElementById("myBtn").disabled = true;

Fonte:
[Button disabled property](https://www.w3schools.com/JSREF/prop_pushbutton_disabled.asp)